# my sql database migration with no down time

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication

We have a gigantic mysql database running on a shared environment with very limited privileges.We need to migrate our running production database to a new infrastructure with no or minimum down time.binary logging and master/slave approach is not option because of the limitations/ policies of the hosting company. Estimated mysqldump process would take at least 4 hours and we need a way to migrate the data and keep tables unlocked and sync with delta data.Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd say its not possible to do. Limited privileges? No way. Database operations like that are, independently of the database, time consuming and usually requires higher privileges to do it right. Once you start the mysqldump you could also run into bigger problems, like memory limitations, etc. If you already know mysqldump takes at least 4 hours, it'll probably take a day to do this kind of maintenance.

Comment: I am thinking about getting a copy of every single sql call at application level during the dump and store it as my homemade binary log. then use it to sync